# git rebase not doing what I expected

Tags: gitlab, rebase

Currently having a little hard time with git. Especially with "git rebase devbranch longtimerefactor"

Skilllevel: kinda beginner, used atlasian sourcetree for a git project around 10 or more years ago. Worklife with TFS/Azure.

Goal: finding a working solution for what I used to do with TFS/Azure and 'shelvesets'. Working on a 'main' project, checking it in unshelve a 'longtime' shelve project, keep working on it and if neede just shelf again, undo what you did in current project (local) add/change a feature commit and back to unshelve.

What I tried: masterbranche -> devbranch (with subbranches for ever sprint) and a 'longtimerefactor'-branche based on devbranche. Every once in a while I thought I'd just use "git rebase devbranch longtimerefactor" to get the newest changes into the refactor-branch and it would all be fine. However, if I (>30 commit ahead) do a git rebase and it's finished and it should look like it is depicted in [git rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) (first result after "would be:") then I'm confused on why -If I straight use the git rebase again- have to merge the last so many commits again. By how it is depicted I'd thought that it will 'realize' "oh nothing to be done" and all fine.

Am I missing something or is the example code just missing some "--onto"? Am I even using the right way do archive what I tried? I even read about the worktrees but it doesn't seem to be the 'smarter' solution for what I tried. And not I can't simply merge the refactor branch into dev as of now :(

Output of "C:\git\workspace\galaxy>git log --oneline --graph --decorate employee-rework master development"

```
* 602c464 (HEAD -> employee-rework, origin/employee-rework) Employee() WIP
* c7e22d8 after rebase...
*   3b8ee0c "Resolve the conflicts and commit the results"
|\
| * 765ee88 get vehicle info cleanup
| * 6d6a8a6 git ignor
| * d97a587 Employee() WIP
| * b5dc143 Employee() WIP 2
| *   94bb179 "merge fun"
| |\
| | * 1adbb8b employee()
| | * 21dd371 Employee() WIP 3
| | * 221b3cb Employee() WIP 4
| | *   40ba32c rebased + merged
| | |\
| | | * e9ba607 Rework of Employee() - WIP - Init
| | * | 7984a02 merged
| | * | 4f0f74e more merge?
| | * | 3f4302c Employee rework() 5
| | * | 725de3a Employee() WIP 6
| | * | d5497ab Employee() WIP 7
| | * | c0615c5 Employee() WIP 8
| | * | b49da67 Rework of Employee() - WIP - Init
| * | | 2a1ef6d Employee() WIP 9
| * | | 3b00c26 employee() pre-rebase
| * | | 24bd4fc employee() WIP 10
| * | | 7e281ac Employee() WIP 11
:...skipping...
* 602c464 (HEAD -> employee-rework, origin/employee-rework) Employee() WIP
* c7e22d8 after rebase...
*   3b8ee0c "Resolve the conflicts and commit the results"
|\
| * 765ee88 get vehicle info cleanup
| * 6d6a8a6 git ignor
| * d97a587 Employee() WIP
| * b5dc143 Employee() WIP 2
| *   94bb179 "merge fun"
| |\
| | * 1adbb8b employee()
| | * 21dd371 Employee() WIP 3
| | * 221b3cb Employee() WIP 4
| | *   40ba32c rebased + merged
| | |\
| | | * e9ba607 Rework of Employee() - WIP - Init
| | * | 7984a02 merged
| | * | 4f0f74e more merge?
| | * | 3f4302c Employee rework() 5
| | * | 725de3a Employee() WIP 6
| | * | d5497ab Employee() WIP 7
| | * | c0615c5 Employee() WIP 8
| | * | b49da67 Rework of Employee() - WIP - Init
| * | | 2a1ef6d Employee() WIP 9
| * | | 3b00c26 employee() pre-rebase
| * | | 24bd4fc employee() WIP 10
| * | | 7e281ac Employee() WIP 11
| * | | 62d3998 Employee() WIP
| * | | b3698ea Rework of Employee() - WIP - Init
:...skipping...
* 602c464 (HEAD -> employee-rework, origin/employee-rework) Employee() WIP
* c7e22d8 after rebase...
*   3b8ee0c "Resolve the conflicts and commit the results"
|\
| * 765ee88 get vehicle info cleanup
| * 6d6a8a6 git ignor
| * d97a587 Employee() WIP
| * b5dc143 Employee() WIP 2
| *   94bb179 "merge fun"
| |\
| | * 1adbb8b employee()
| | * 21dd371 Employee() WIP 3
| | * 221b3cb Employee() WIP 4
| | *   40ba32c rebased + merged
| | |\
| | | * e9ba607 Rework of Employee() - WIP - Init
| | * | 7984a02 merged
| | * | 4f0f74e more merge?
| | * | 3f4302c Employee rework() 5
| | * | 725de3a Employee() WIP 6
| | * | d5497ab Employee() WIP 7
| | * | c0615c5 Employee() WIP 8
| | * | b49da67 Rework of Employee() - WIP - Init
| * | | 2a1ef6d Employee() WIP 9
| * | | 3b00c26 employee() pre-rebase
| * | | 24bd4fc employee() WIP 10
| * | | 7e281ac Employee() WIP 11
| * | | 62d3998 Employee() WIP
| * | | b3698ea Rework of Employee() - WIP - Init
| * | | c8c401c merged just an other time
| * | | e86a84c merge :(
| * | | 115ef28 Employee() WIP 12
| * | | e56f80b Employee() WIP 13
| * | | fa0c4c3 Employee() WIP 14
| * | | 86f2a01 Employee() WIP 15
:...skipping...
* 602c464 (HEAD -> employee-rework, origin/employee-rework) Employee() WIP
* c7e22d8 after rebase...
*   3b8ee0c "Resolve the conflicts and commit the results"
|\
| * 765ee88 get vehicle info cleanup
| * 6d6a8a6 git ignor
| * d97a587 Employee() WIP
| * b5dc143 Employee() WIP 2
| *   94bb179 "merge fun"
| |\
| | * 1adbb8b employee()
| | * 21dd371 Employee() WIP 3
| | * 221b3cb Employee() WIP 4
| | *   40ba32c rebased + merged
| | |\
| | | * e9ba607 Rework of Employee() - WIP - Init
| | * | 7984a02 merged
| | * | 4f0f74e more merge?
| | * | 3f4302c Employee rework() 5
| | * | 725de3a Employee() WIP 6
| | * | d5497ab Employee() WIP 7
| | * | c0615c5 Employee() WIP 8
| | * | b49da67 Rework of Employee() - WIP - Init
| * | | 2a1ef6d Employee() WIP 9
| * | | 3b00c26 employee() pre-rebase
| * | | 24bd4fc employee() WIP 10
| * | | 7e281ac Employee() WIP 11
| * | | 62d3998 Employee() WIP
| * | | b3698ea Rework of Employee() - WIP - Init
| * | | c8c401c merged just an other time
| * | | e86a84c merge :(
| * | | 115ef28 Employee() WIP 12
| * | | e56f80b Employee() WIP 13
| * | | fa0c4c3 Employee() WIP 14
| * | | 86f2a01 Employee() WIP 15
| * | | 1bfda2e Rework of Employee() - WIP - Init
* | | | f3fe064 get vehicle info cleanup
* | | | 70f5309 Employee() WIP 16
* | | | bbe3e0d Employee() WIP 17
:...skipping...
* 602c464 (HEAD -> employee-rework, origin/employee-rework) Employee() WIP
* c7e22d8 after rebase...
*   3b8ee0c "Resolve the conflicts and commit the results"
|\
| * 765ee88 get vehicle info cleanup
| * 6d6a8a6 git ignor
| * d97a587 Employee() WIP
| * b5dc143 Employee() WIP 2
| *   94bb179 "merge fun"
| |\
| | * 1adbb8b employee()
| | * 21dd371 Employee() WIP 3
| | * 221b3cb Employee() WIP 4
| | *   40ba32c rebased + merged
| | |\
| | | * e9ba607 Rework of Employee() - WIP - Init
| | * | 7984a02 merged
| | * | 4f0f74e more merge?
| | * | 3f4302c Employee rework() 5
| | * | 725de3a Employee() WIP 6
| | * | d5497ab Employee() WIP 7
| | * | c0615c5 Employee() WIP 8
| | * | b49da67 Rework of Employee() - WIP - Init
| * | | 2a1ef6d Employee() WIP 9
| * | | 3b00c26 employee() pre-rebase
| * | | 24bd4fc employee() WIP 10
| * | | 7e281ac Employee() WIP 11
| * | | 62d3998 Employee() WIP
| * | | b3698ea Rework of Employee() - WIP - Init
| * | | c8c401c merged just an other time
| * | | e86a84c merge :(
| * | | 115ef28 Employee() WIP 12
| * | | e56f80b Employee() WIP 13
| * | | fa0c4c3 Employee() WIP 14
| * | | 86f2a01 Employee() WIP 15
| * | | 1bfda2e Rework of Employee() - WIP - Init
* | | | f3fe064 get vehicle info cleanup
* | | | 70f5309 Employee() WIP 16
* | | | bbe3e0d Employee() WIP 17
* | | | 298fac8 employee()
* | | | 9a8a5d6 2022-08-08 employee() WIP
* | | | e009551 Employee() WIP
:...skipping...
* 602c464 (HEAD -> employee-rework, origin/employee-rework) Employee() WIP
* c7e22d8 after rebase...
*   3b8ee0c "Resolve the conflicts and commit the results"
|\
| * 765ee88 get vehicle info cleanup
| * 6d6a8a6 git ignor
| * d97a587 Employee() WIP
| * b5dc143 Employee() WIP 2
| *   94bb179 "merge fun"
| |\
| | * 1adbb8b employee()
| | * 21dd371 Employee() WIP 3
| | * 221b3cb Employee() WIP 4
| | *   40ba32c rebased + merged
| | |\
| | | * e9ba607 Rework of Employee() - WIP - Init
| | * | 7984a02 merged
| | * | 4f0f74e more merge?
| | * | 3f4302c Employee rework() 5
| | * | 725de3a Employee() WIP 6
| | * | d5497ab Employee() WIP 7
| | * | c0615c5 Employee() WIP 8
| | * | b49da67 Rework of Employee() - WIP - Init
| * | | 2a1ef6d Employee() WIP 9
| * | | 3b00c26 employee() pre-rebase
| * | | 24bd4fc employee() WIP 10
| * | | 7e281ac Employee() WIP 11
| * | | 62d3998 Employee() WIP
| * | | b3698ea Rework of Employee() - WIP - Init
| * | | c8c401c merged just an other time
| * | | e86a84c merge :(
| * | | 115ef28 Employee() WIP 12
| * | | e56f80b Employee() WIP 13
| * | | fa0c4c3 Employee() WIP 14
| * | | 86f2a01 Employee() WIP 15
| * | | 1bfda2e Rework of Employee() - WIP - Init
* | | | f3fe064 get vehicle info cleanup
* | | | 70f5309 Employee() WIP 16
* | | | bbe3e0d Employee() WIP 17
* | | | 298fac8 employee()
* | | | 9a8a5d6 2022-08-08 employee() WIP
* | | | e009551 Employee() WIP
* | | | 683b122 Rework of Employee() - WIP - Init
* | | | 4d4c67e some merge
* | | | 2782354 Employee rework()
:
```

Comment: can you show as a `git log --oneline --graph --decorate longtimerefactor masterbranch devbranch` tree to understand better?

Also, `However, if I (>30 commit ahead) do a git rebase and it's finished and it should look like it is depicted` which rebase do you mean? rebaseing devbranch to master, or longtimerefactor to devbranch?

Comment: From my logical understanding I had devbranch and branched the longtimerefactor off of it and hence (if the command in the initial post is correct) I rebased the longtimerefactor onto a newer version of the devbranch. - Working on the "git log" have to anonymize the commits..

Comment: If you use the `oneline` you will only have the message, not the author

Comment: Added to the original post - and yeh it's a "have to" not a "i want to" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Understanding the situation

Your development looks more like:

```
    o---o---o---o---o  masterbranche
         \
          o---o---o---o---o  devbranch
                           \
                            o---o---o  longtimeRefactor
```

### Why it happened

All happy hippos until you rebased. When you rebased, you didn't only moved the base commit where `longtimeRefactor` was branched, but introduced conflicts. At same point, `devbranch` and `longtimeRefactor` modified the same code at some line, and a conflict was raised. That conflict requires a merge commit to be solved.  You have to resolve the merge conflicts and continue rebasing. Nothing to do.

You can rebase more often to suffer less from this pattern.
The lesson here is that rebasing will be easier when you are as updated as you can from the base branch. The same applies to merging.

### Alternatives

Alternatively, if what you want is a cleaner history, you can use merge with the `--squash` option, and keep the historic base branch if you need to go back to any stage or `cherry-pick` a commit.

Comment: yeh that's what I thought my git would look like :). However if I'm on the latest version of the devbranch and do a rebase, I'd expect something as "nothing to rebase" whereas I had to start to merge again :confused: . A ''--squash'' = 'merge do dev with next commit'? Whereas I'd just love to update refactor with the meanwhile done changes in dev. Hence I did the rebase by my logical understanding (which seems to be off)

Comment: Your understanding is right. It is just that you need to merge when tou have a conflict. :)